# Why Pygame only plays the last sound?

Tags: python, audio, pygame

i got this code:

```
a_0 = pygame.mixer.sound("a.mp3",)
a = pygame.mixer.music

b_0 = pygame.mixer.music.load("b.mp3")
b = pygame.mixer.music

c_0 = pygame.mixer.music.load("c.mp3",)
c   = pygame.mixer.music

d_0 = pygame.mixer.music.load("d.mp3")
d   = pygame.mixer.music

e_0 = pygame.mixer.music.load("e.mp3",)
e = pygame.mixer.music
```

When i wanna use to play sound `d (that emans d.mp3)` with:

```
d.play()
```

it only plays the last sound of the list, that means `e.mp3` instead of `d.mp3`.
What i am doing wrong here?

Comment: What list are you talking about?

Comment: It's not a real Python list. It is just a folder of the sounds. The folder contains all sounds used in the code.

Comment: could this line 'e_0 = pygame.mixer.music.load("e.mp3",)' be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pygame.music.mixer.load()` does not return anything. So you can't assign it to a variable. It loads is into the mixer and prepares it for playback. [Documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.load)

You need to have a list or dictionary of songs you want to play, then whenever you want to play one, you need to load it into the mixer and play it:

```
def play_song(name):
    pygame.mixer.music.load(name)
    pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(0.3)  # you can also set the volume
    pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=-1)
```

This is specifically for `mixer.music`.

`pygame.mixer.Sound` returns a Sound object which you can save for later: [documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Sound). So you can load a directory of sounds into a python list.

```
sounds_list = []
sounds_list.append(pygame.mixer.Sound('gun_fire.wav'))
sounds_list.append(pygame.mixer.Sound('coin_pickup.wav'))
# add more sounds
```

Comment: thanks so much! Is there a chance to show me how to load the sounds from a list?

Comment: You can't load music and save for later, but you can load Sounds

Comment: Usually I will have mixer.music playing in the background and mixer.Sounds playing over top of the music on different Channels

Comment: Yeah, this is something i misunderstood. So basically i need a list and load each sound everytime when i wanna play()?

Comment: if you want to use mixer.music to play music, you need to load it every time. if you use mixer.Sound, you can load them into a list